# Jquery click function inside each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, each

When I click .zoom in this example, I inject 20 (the amount of items in the loop) .big_image divs.  I'd just like to insert one, relative to the item I am clicking.

```
$('.main img').each(function() {
var img = this;
$('.zoom').click(function() {
    $(this).after('<div class="big_image"><img src="'+$(img).attr('src')+'"></div>');
});
});
```

I have simplified the script right down here.  Ideally I'd just like to know how to modify the click function (if possible) as there are other things going on not related to the question. Thanks!

**EDIT: Working example [here](http://houseofyum.co.uk/static/gallery/index3.html).**

The zoom button should appear on at least the first 2 images in the gallery (top left corner).  If it's confusing, I'm trying to get the zoom button to only appear on very long/tall images.  I'm also aware that I should split the setClass function up but haven't learned how to do that yet :)

Comment: you shouldn't bind the `.zoom` click in the each loop - you will be doing the same bind multiple times (unless you added $(this).closest('.zoom'))

Comment: what is `.zoom` what is `.main`, can you post the html too? like pete above said, you don't have to put click handler inside each

Comment: You're adding a click listener to every .zoom element for every image. Please show us a bit of your html so we can give more specific help.

Comment: .main is the container, .zoom is injected based on different parameters within the each loop.  The html is simply the container and an unordered list with images.  Sorry I would put the whole thing online but there are many other things wrong with it which would distract everyone! :)

Comment: updated the question with working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person who answered this removed their answer for some reason!  The key is .next()

```
var img = this;
$(this).next('.zoom').click(function() {
    $(this).after('<div class="big_image"><img src="'+$(img).attr('src')+'"></div>'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.zoom').click(function(e){
     var imgURL= $(this).parents('.main').find('img').attr('src');
     $(this).after('<div class="big_image"><img src="'+imgURL+'"></div>')
});
```

if `.main` container is the immediate parent of both the `img` and `.zoom` you can use

```
var imgURL= $(this).siblings('img').attr('src');
```

if it HAS to be inside the loop. try modifying your code like below

```
 var flag=false;
 $('.main img').each(function() {
   var img = this;
    $('.zoom').click(function() {
     if(!flag)
        $(this).after('<div class="big_image"><img src="'+$(img).attr('src')+'"></div>');
     flag=true;
   });
 });
```

Comment: that has the same behaviour as my code above, i updated the example URL

Comment: PS. outside the setClass function (and thus the each loop) it does nothing

Comment: if you look in the code you'll see it injects a 20 .big_image divs, it just so happens that the correct one is on top.

Comment: try alerting something inside .zoom click, how many times you get the alert message?, it shouldn't be inside the each loop!!